# Using Named Pipes to communicate from Windows Service to GUI Frontend in Delphi

Tags: delphi, named-pipes, delphi-10.3-rio

I'm using Russell Libby's Pipes.PAS unit to facilitate communicating between two programs using named pipes. I have made a working example using one server (VCL program with GUI) and one client (also VCL) that can be started multiple times, and I can communicate back and forth between these.

However, when I run the same server code in a Windows service, I can see the client connecting in the service (I log to a text file), but when the service broadcasts a message to be read by the client(s), nothing happens on the client side.

Are there any special things that need to be done in order for the Named Pipe to work from a Windows Service to a Frontend GUI program?

I construct the Server Pipe as follows:

```
  Pipe:=TPipeServer.Create(Self);
  Pipe.Name:='Pipe';
  Pipe.OnPipeMessage:=PipePipeMessage;
  Pipe.OnPipeConnect:=PipePipeConnect;
  Pipe.OnPipeDisconnect:=PipePipeDisconnect;
  Pipe.PipeName := 'Service';
  Pipe.Active:=TRUE;
```

and the client side:

```
  Pipe:=TPipeClient.Create(NIL);
  Pipe.Name:='Pipe';
  Pipe.MemoryThrottle:=10240000;
  Pipe.PipeName := 'Service';
  Pipe.OnPipeMessage:=PipePipeMessage;
```

but I never get the code at PipePipeMessage executed.

Am I missing something? Like I said, the server side code in Connected gets executed, so there is a connection set up...

Comment: You need to secure the pipe

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Any tip as to how I'll do that? Is it a parameter/bitmask in the CreateNamedPipe call? And/Or the CreateFile call? On Client side and/or Server side?

Comment: When I did this (some time ago) I used this sort of code.

`var
  SA: TSecurityAttributes;
...
  SA.nLength := SizeOf(SA);
  SA.bInheritHandle := True;
  ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor(
    'D:(A;OICI;GRGW;;;AU)',//discretionary ACL to allow read/write access for authenticated users
    SDDL_REVISION_1,
    SA.lpSecurityDescriptor,
    nil
  );
...`

You then pass `@SA` to `CreateNamedPipe`. No idea how to fit that into the library you use.

Comment: And you'd need to put it in the global namespace also so that it can be seen from a different session

Comment: Pipe Names need to have a special format.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ipc/pipe-names for details.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I have implemented your SecurityAttributes in the library, but don't know how to "put it in the global namespace". According to an article I found on the net, Named Pipes don't have Global or Local name spaces. Also, the TSecurityAttributes - should they be used in both CreateNamedPipe and the subsequent CreateFile and/or both on the Server side and the Client side? I am already using the \\.\pipe\PipeName format (the library takes care of that), and as I said, the system works with two GUI programs, but not when the server is running as a service.

Comment: Perhaps I misremembered about the namespaces

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Possibly. In any case, do you know which calls I should implement the Security Attributes? At the moment I do it everywhere, but it still doesn't work. Any tips you have would be appreciated...

Comment: I've done this before but I can't be bothered to dig out my old code.

Answer (score 0):

There's an updated/forked version on GitHub now:
https://github.com/superflexible/NamedPipesForDelphi

I am using this with a service myself and it works fine. Yes it needs a messaging system, i.e. the VCL, or a non-GUI replacement.